# LIKE operator issue 'maha,delhi'

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Declare @PackageID varchar(50)
Declare @state varchar(50)
set @PackageID='2,4,5'
set @state='delhi,maha'

    select DetailsID,Industry,StateID from DetailsMaster 
    where ((Industry IN (SELECT * from fnList2Table (@PackageID)))
    or 
    ((StateID like '%' +(SELECT top 1  [s] from dbo.Split(',', @state)) + '%') 
    ))


Union

select DetailsID,Industry,StateID from DetailsMaster 
where ((Industry IN (SELECT * from fnList2Table (@PackageID)))
or 
((StateID like '%' +(SELECT top 1  [s] from dbo.Split(',', Reverse(@state))) + '%') 
))
```

The above query is not fethching result of State `kk,maha`. It will fetch result of `maha,kk`.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your `Reverse(@state)` isn't switching `delhi,maha` to `maha,delhi`.

What [Reverse](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_reverse) actually does is convert `delhi,maha` to `aham,ihled`.

You can try cutting the string yourself with [substr_index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) and then reassembling it in reverse with [concat_ws](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws):

```
CONCAT_WS(',', SUBSTRING_INDEX(@state,',',-1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(@state,',',1))
```